# batch choice command with errorlevel isn't working

Tags: batch-file

I am getting confused with the choice command.
here is my code:

```
@echo off
:start
cls
echo yes or no?
Choice/c yn
if errorlevel 1 goto yes
if errorlevel 2 goto no
:yes
echo you pressed yes
pause
goto start
:no
echo you pressed no
pause
goto start
```

the problem is every time I get yes.  I figured out if I used this:

```
set x=%errorlevel%
```

and then used

```
if %x%==1 goto yes
if %x%==2 goto no
```

and the script workes fine.  Why is this?  I think I remember reading something about checking errorlevel could actually set a new errorlevel if false, or something like that.  A little help?

Comment: If errorlevel 1 if not errorlevel 2 goto yes and if errorlevel 2 if not errorlevel 3 goto no

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The construct `if errorlevel n` checks if the errorlevel is at least n. So if errorlevel is 4, then the tests `if errorlevel 1` to `if errorlevel 4`, all of them, return true.

The way to do the test is go from higher errorlevel to lower errorlevel

```
if errorlevel 2 goto no
if errorlevel 1 goto yes
```

Comment: I tried that too and no matter how I arranged the numbers I always got yes.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the syntax MC ND mentioned, or you use the more clearly syntax of

```
if %errorlevel%==1 goto yes
if %errorlevel%==2 goto no
```

Comment: Except %errorlevel% is not exactly the same as errorlevel. If errorlevel 1 works foolproof.