# Batch file termination issue

Tags: batch-file

Having an issue with my batch program exiting for apparently no reason. I've found that if you use 0 it works ok, but 1 exits , and 2 runs 1??? makes no sense seeing how 0 and 1 are almost complete copies of each other. any help would be appreciated. As a side note I do have choice.exe and the dev tools to use cecopy.

Here's my code:

```
@echo off
title MK2XXX Depot test
rem Automation for MK2xxx app/plat copying
rem v 0.01

:main
echo MK2xxx App/Plat copyBot
echo v 0.01
echo.
echo Please select your unit:
echo 0 MK2046
echo 1 MK2250
echo 2 Exit
:: prompt user for which unit they wish to copy files to

choice /c:012 /n
        if %errorlevel% == 0 goto MK2046 
        if %errorlevel% == 1 goto MK2250 
        if %errorlevel% == 2 goto end   


:MK2046
cls

echo Make sure you have allowed pcConnection on unit
echo Connect RS 485 cable, press enter once Sync is complete
    :: wait until unit is synced properly
pause
cls
cecopy C:\"FILEPATH dev:\Application\
cecopy C:\"FILEPATH dev:\Application\
cecopy C:\"FILEPATH dev:\Application\
cecopy C:\"FILEPATH
cecopy C:\"FILEPATH
pause
goto main




:MK2250
cls
pause
echo Make sure you have allowed pcConnection on unit
echo Connect RS 485 cable, press enter once Sync is complete
    :: wait until unit is synced properly
pause
cls
cecopy C:\"FILEPATH
cecopy C:\"FILEPATH
cecopy C:\"FILEPATH dev:\Application\
cecopy C:\"FILEPATH
cecopy C:\"FILEPATH
pause
goto main

:end
```

Comment: Please, see [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/21534680/2861476)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok the problem is the IF you are using it can be unpredictable this is a more stable one that you should use. As there can be other things that can effect the errorlevel.

```
set /p result=Choice:
if %result%==0 goto MK2046
if %result%==1 goto MK2250
if %result%==2 goto end
```

So your code should be like this:

```
@echo off
title MK2XXX Depot test
rem Automation for MK2xxx app/plat copying
rem v 0.01

:main
echo MK2xxx App/Plat copyBot
echo v 0.01
echo.
echo Please select your unit:
echo 0 MK2046
echo 1 MK2250
echo 2 Exit
:: prompt user for which unit they wish to copy files to

set /p result=Choice:
if %result%==0 goto MK2046
if %result%==1 goto MK2250
if %result%==2 goto end 


:MK2046
cls

echo Make sure you have allowed pcConnection on unit
echo Connect RS 485 cable, press enter once Sync is complete
    :: wait until unit is synced properly
pause
cls
cecopy C:\"Flash 2"\MK2046-xxxxxxxx\"Depot Test"\App\*.reg dev:\Application\
cecopy C:\"Flash 2"\MK2046-xxxxxxxx\"Depot Test"\App\*.key dev:\Application\
cecopy C:\"Flash 2"\MK2046-xxxxxxxx\"Depot Test"\App\radio.def dev:\Application\
cecopy C:\"Flash 2"\MK2046-xxxxxxxx\"Depot Test"\Plat\*.reg dev:\Platform\
cecopy C:\"Flash 2"\MK2046-xxxxxxxx\"Depot Test"\Plat\*.cpy dev:\Platform\
pause
goto main




:MK2250
cls
pause
echo Make sure you have allowed pcConnection on unit
echo Connect RS 485 cable, press enter once Sync is complete
    :: wait until unit is synced properly
pause
cls
cecopy C:\"Flash 2"\MK2250-xxxxxxxx\"Depot Test"\App\*.reg dev:\Application\
cecopy C:\"Flash 2"\MK2250-xxxxxxxx\"Depot Test"\App\*.key dev:\Application\
cecopy C:\"Flash 2"\MK2250-xxxxxxxx\"Depot Test"\App\radio.def dev:\Application\
cecopy C:\"Flash 2"\MK2250-xxxxxxxx\"Depot Test"\Plat\*.reg dev:\Platform\
cecopy C:\"Flash 2"\MK2250-xxxxxxxx\"Depot Test"\Plat\*.cpy dev:\Platform\
pause
goto main

:end
```

Give that a go.

Comment: That worked flawlessly, no I just have to smooth out the cecopy lines apparently         `Parameter processing error - Too many parameters:  dev:\Application`

Answer (score 0):

`choice` gives an `%errorlevel%` 1 for the first choice (`0`), not 0. So your Code should look like:

```
choice /c:012 /n
        if %errorlevel% == 1 goto MK2046 
        if %errorlevel% == 2 goto MK2250 
        if %errorlevel% == 3 goto end
```

maybe less confusing when using letters instead of numbers: `choice /c:abc` with Input `a` gives an `%errorlevel%` of 1 (first letter)